# Debug all properties of a typescript type

Tags: typescript

I often have some types composed of different types e.g.

```
type Foo = { a: number }
type Bar = { b: string }

type Baz = Foo & Bar
```

How can I print out or in any other way see all the underlying properties and types of Baz. More or less the equivalent of `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2))` but for types eg

```
inspect(Baz) //  { a: number; b: string }
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you could do something like this:

```
type Foo = { a: number }
type Bar = { b: string }

type Baz = Foo & Bar

const test: Baz = { a: 12, b: 'Hello' };

Object.keys(test).map(key => console.log(key,'=>', test[key], typeof(test[key]) ));
```

The output will be:

```
a => 12 number
b => Hello string
```

Of course you can adjust the debug layout in any way you like.

Comment: No I'm looking to inspect types not runtime values